# Why linux sort is not giving me desired results?

Tags: linux, csv, shell, sorting

I have a file a.csv with contents similar to below

```
a,b,c
a  ,aa,  a
a b, c, f
a , b, c
a b a b a,a,a
a,a,a
a aa ,a , t
```

I am trying to sort it by using  `sort -k1 -t, a.csv`
But it is giving following results

```
a,a,a
a  ,aa,  a
a aa ,a , t
a b a b a,a,a
a , b, c
a,b,c
a b, c, f
```

Which is not the actual sort on 1st column.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to specify the end position to be 1, too:

```
sort -k1,1 -t, a.csv
```

Comment: Oh. k1,1 seems for number of columns to be sorted. But will this work if words are even more worse.

Answer (score 2):

Give this a try: `sort -t, -k1,1 a.csv`

The man suggests that omitting the end field, it will sort on all characters starting at field `n` until the end of the line:

```
-k POS1[,POS2]'
     The recommended, POSIX, option for specifying a sort field.  The
     field consists of the part of the line between POS1 and POS2 (or
     the end of the line, if POS2 is omitted), _inclusive_.  Fields and
     character positions are numbered starting with 1.  So to sort on
     the second field, you'd use `-k 2,2' See below for more examples.
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead:

```
sort -k 1,1 -t , a.csv
```

sort reads `-k 1` as "sort from first field onwards" -- thus effectively defying the point of passing the argument in the first place.

This is documented in the [sort man page](http://ss64.com/bash/sort.html) and warned about in the Examples section:

> *Sort numerically on the second field
>   and resolve ties by sorting
>   alphabetically on the third and fourth
>   characters of field five. Use `:' as
>   the field delimiter:*
>
> `$ sort -t : -k 2,2n -k 5.3,5.4`
>
> Note that if you had written `-k 2` instead
>   of `-k 2,2`, `sort` would have used all
>   characters beginning in the second
>   field and extending to the end of the
>   line as the primary *numeric* key. For
>   the large majority of applications,
>   treating keys spanning more than one
>   field as numeric will not do what you
>   expect.

Comment: It's the -n switch used for the example.